# Create human readable URL search strings

Tags: php, url, encoding

I just implemented a search function into my program. If a search string is sent, the program dose this:

```
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    header('Location: /search/'.rawurlencode($_GET['s']));
    exit;
}
```

The only problem I have is that the resulting search string URL isn't really human readable, e.g. the search term `is 500€ a lot of money` results into `is%20500€%20a%20lot%20of%20money`. I would like to build a more human readable search URL, e.g. `is+500€+a+lot+of+money`.

Is there a simple way of doing this or do you have to encode the string manually, e.g. look for spaces, etc. and replace them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) instead of `rawurlencode`. This uses `+` for spaces rather than `%20`.

Comment: Thanks! My bad! I just could have read the two topics under rawurldecode rawurlencode in the PHP Docs.